# Jersey client config for JAXBElement

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jaxb, jersey

I have a REST service which has the Response object as below:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="testresponse")
    class Test{

        private Map<String, String> prop = new TreeMap<>();

        @JsonAnyGetter
        @XmlTransient
        public Map<String, String> getJSONProp() {
            return prop;
        }


        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        @JsonIgnore
        public List<JAXBElement<String>> getXMLProp() {
            List<JAXBElement<String>>  el = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : prop.entrySet()) {
                el.add(new JAXBElement<>(new QName(entry.getKey()), String.class, entry.getValue()));
            }
            return el;
        }
        @JsonAnySetter
        public void addProp(String key, String value) {
             prop.put(key, value);
        }

        public void setProp(Map<String, String> prop) {
             this.prop = prop;
        }

    }
```

The method is getXMLProp() is used for XML response in which the tag names matches the key of the Map prop.The method getJSONProp is used for  JSON response.

When i try to invoke the service from postman client it works fine but when i try to invoke the service with jersey client the response doesn't have the data.Can some one pls suggest how the JAXBElement can be populated in the response?

Also the reponse.getJSONProp() throws below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
```

Jersey version: 1.12.
Jackson version : 1.9.2

The Jersey client config is as below:

```
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig jerseyConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    jerseyConfig.getClasses().add(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
    Client c = Client.create(jerseyConfig);
```

MediaType used in jersey client is MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.
Can some one suggest what I am missing here ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `getProp()` a REST service method? It isn't annoated to be, and with annotations like `@JsonIgnore`, it doesn't seem to be, so why did you say that it is a service method? (I read "service with method" to mean "service method" aka the method *handling* the service request)

Comment: *"The method is"* then you show a method that seems identical to `getXMLProp()`, except it's named `getProp()`, and no context of where "the method" is, and what it is used for.

Comment: During serialization, the getter is called. During DEserialization, the setter is called. So you probably want to show the setter in this situation since this is a deserialization problem.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Yeah I don't work much with JAXB, but from what you are showing, it seems that there is no JAXB equivalent of the Jackson `@JsonAnySetter`. So there is no way for the unknown values to get set.

Comment: Maybe see if you can just convince your team to add the new Jackson dependency we discussed in your previous question. This would make everything so much easier. This would just work. The `@JsonAnySetter` would be used if you let Jackson handle the XML.